# automatic resolve member function with const postfix

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Inside my class I have 2 algorithms that should be applied depending if container supports `lower_bound`.

```
template <class T>
class SmartContainerHandler{
....
template <class Q=T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Q::lower_bound)>::value >::type
foo_impl(int k, double _ = 0)
{
    auto r = _t.lower_bound(k);
    std::cout << "has lower_bound" << (r == _t.end() ? -1 : *r) << std::endl;
}
template <class Q=T>
typename std::enable_if<! std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&Q::lower_bound)>::value >::type
foo_impl(int k)
{
    std::cout << << "no lower_bound, just a key:" << k <<  std:: endl;
}
```

For example I would like to instantiate either with  `SmartContainerHandler<std::set<int> >` or `SmartContainerHandler<std::vector<int> >`

My problem that `lower_bound` has 2 signatures

```
template< class K > iterator lower_bound(const K& x);
template< class K > const_iterator lower_bound(const K& x) const;
```

(just try to compile this without success `auto m = &std::set<int>::lower_bound`)

In my particular case I don't care about `const` signature, but in sake of more generic question: How to check method exists if provided 2 or more signatures?

Comment: Do you want a way to distinguish no-overload / one-overload / two-overloads (e.g., const / non-const)? Or simply a way to distinguish no-overload / one or more overloads?

Comment: @Holt The best for me - let the compiler provide best overload. But  I understand that from expression`&Q::lower_bound` it is impossible. So const/non-const is a good way to specify correct choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply rely on *expression SFINAE* here, something like:

```
template <class Q=T>
auto foo_impl(int k, double _ = 0)
    -> decltype(std::declval<Q&>().lower_bound(k), void())
{
    auto r = _t.lower_bound(k);
    std::cout << "has lower_bound" << (r == _t.end() ? -1 : *r) << std::endl;
}

void foo_impl(int k, ...)
{
    std::cout << << "no lower_bound, just a key:" << k <<  std:: endl;
}
```

The first `foo_impl` overload will be discarded if `std::declval<Q&>().lower_bound(k)` is not a valid expression.

Comment: Looking promising but doesn't work. Here is my sandbox http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1991cace8871b95b that twice prints `no lower_bound, just a key:6
no lower_bound, just a key:6`

Comment: @Dewfy It only requires minor tweaks: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b644b93488a04da

Comment: @VittorioRomeo super!